# hyperv replica multiple sites

Tags: windows, hyper-v, replication

I wanted to know if that is possible with a hyper-v replica before I start with the implementation.

I have 3 sites hosting 3 stand-alone hyper-v servers (acting as primary) and I wanted to set up a single replica server for the 3 sites. all servers are in workgroup mode. Are there any special requirements to set up this configuration?

In case of Site A failed and I have to switch the replica server as primary, does it affect the other sites B and C?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion or help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Hyper-V replication, you are replicating individual VMs. If you replicate VMs from multiple Hyper-V hosts to a single central location, it shouldn't matter from the Hyper-V perspective if you fail over one or a couple VMs.

Comment: so you mean it is on VM level and not on Virtual Host level, right? what about sites B and C will they remain to replicate normally?